# Как открыть Form2 из Form1 (усложнёно, не дубликат)

Tags: c#, winforms

Понадобилось мне вызвать с одной формы другую, но вот в чём загвоздка. Если я пишу:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.show();
```

При этом я учитываю названия формы. Но как сделать так же, но с `MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm`?

Нужно связать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал что-то типа этого:

```
MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm form2 = new MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm ();
form2.Show();
```

Но в итоге оно открывает пустую форму метро-фраймворка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: картинки надо вставлять картинками, а не давать ссылки на внешний хостинг, где они протухнут через неделю. А код картинками (О, у меня первая наконец загрузилась!) это вообще моветон: вставляйте код текстом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вышеприведенный код создает экземпляр класса, на котором вызывается метод (в данном случае Show()). Как следствие во втором случае надо так же создать класс, на скрине у вас он называется: "FrmMain".
Так что код открытия будет выглядеть как:

```
FrmMain form = new FrmMain();
form.Show();
```

мы указываем конкретное имя класса (формы).